# Get all defined field choices from Django app

Tags: python, django

isn't there some util or function, which would iterate through all models in a django app and return something like

```
Model.field: {
    key->String
}
```

values for every choice field defined on a model? Or do I have to write it myself? :)

Answer (score 0):

ok, so i created a short snippet myself

```
from django.apps import apps
import json
print_data = {}
for model in apps.get_models():
    model_name = model._meta.db_table
    for field in model._meta.fields:
        if field.choices:
            try:
                json.dumps(dict(field.choices))  # Exclude weird choices
            except:
                continue
            print_data[model_name] = print_data.get(model_name, {})
            print_data[model_name][str(field.name)] = dict(field.choices)
print(json.dumps(print_data, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
```